# Sorted list items

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sortedlist

Is it possible to add items to sorted list with the same value, because when I am trying to do so it shows me an error:
"An entry with the same key already exists."
If it's possible, then how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Sortable collection which allows duplicate keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716423/c-sharp-sortable-collection-which-allows-duplicate-keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible* to add duplicate keys as stated by other users.

In c# you might be able to use the Lookup class instead, which allows multiple values to be stored with the same key.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx

* It is possible, see comments, but only by defining a comparitor that never returns equality for equal items, which IMO is a really really bad idea.

Comment: It's possible. See [Knasterbax's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21886340/224976) to a similar question

Comment: That solution breaks a precondition of the container (that two equal keys will return equality), and as commenters have pointed out that introduces a raft of other problems. Best to use the container intended for use in this fashion IMO. That said I will update my answer.

Comment: Good point. The comments in Kasterbax's answer reveal some caveats

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible.  The keys must be unique.

Comment: It's possible. See [Knasterbax's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21886340/224976) to a similar question

Comment: Using Kasterbax's answer has caveats. Read the comments

Answer (score 0):

Key should be unique. See this in MSDN

```
ArgumentException   - An element with the specified key already exists in the SortedList object.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.add.aspx

Comment: It's possible. See [Knasterbax's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21886340/224976) to a similar question

Answer (score 0):

Define a class that implements `IComparer`. When you instantiate the `SortedList`, you pass in an instance of your class. Check out [Knasterbax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21886340/224976).

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert multiple key with same name but you can insert multiple value using the same object. You don't need to used unique object.

I am showing an example

```
       SortedList sortedList = new SortedList()
       {
           { "Ind", "India" },
           { "Inda", "India" },
           { "BD", "Bangladesh" },
           { "SA", "South Africa" },
           {"SL", "Sri Lanka" },
           {"UAE", "United of Arab Emirates" },
           {"USA", "United States of America" }
       };

       Console.WriteLine("Sorted List Elements");

       foreach(DictionaryEntry item in sortedList)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"Key: {item.Key}, Value: {item.Value}");
       }
```

Here, I have taken 7 examples. First two are most similar, I have just change the key not the objects. Objects are the are same.
I think you got my point.