# C# SortedSet element equality

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm wondering how can I change way in which SortedSet determines whether two objects are equal.

I have `SortedSet<Tuple<Edge, int>>(new Helpers.EdgeDistanceComparer())` and Comparer method is:

```
public class EdgeDistanceComparer : IComparer<Tuple<Edge,int>>
{
    public int Compare(Tuple<Edge, int> x, Tuple<Edge, int> y)
    {
        return Comparer.Default.Compare(x.Item2, y.Item2);
    }
}
```

I believe because of this Sorted set compares only integers (Tuple.Item2), how can I do comparison on  Edge class

**EDIT**

To explain question more:

I want to compare items by Edge class, and to sort them by Tuple.Item2, and if two Tuple.Item2 are equal, I want to add that item to SortedSet, nevertheless.

**EDIT 2**

Ben Gave good answer but in the end I've decided to add one more property to my class so that value I kept in Tuple.Item2 is now being saved inside property of my Edge class. And then I implemented IComparable interface, so here is how my Edge class looks like:

```
public class Edge : IComparable
{
    public Coordinate Coordinates { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Edge Parent { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }


    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        var thatEdge = (Edge) obj;
        if (Cost > thatEdge.Cost)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (Cost < thatEdge.Cost)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        // cost may be same but coordinates must be different
        if (Cost == thatEdge.Cost &&
            (Coordinates.X != thatEdge.Coordinates.X || Coordinates.Y != thatEdge.Coordinates.Y))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And IComparer for SortedSet:

```
   public class EdgeDistanceComparer : IComparer<Edge>
    {
        public int Compare(Edge x, Edge y)
        {
            return Comparer.Default.Compare(x, y);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Let me just check I understand what you want: you want the second item of the tuple to be used for the sorting, but the first item of the tuple to be used for equality comparison?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want.

Comment: And if you have two Tuples with different `Edges`, but the same `int`, you want them to both appear in the set?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716423/c-sharp-sortable-collection-which-allows-duplicate-keys/21625939#21625939) to another question contains the closest thing you'll get to what you want

In this case the `TValue` is your `Tuple<Edge,int>`, so your `IComparer` that's passed in on construction would be the same as the one in your post.

The only other addition, to make it behave like a `Set`, is to add a check to the `Add` method to only add to the collection if the collection does not already contain an item with the same `Edge`. One way to do that would be:

```
public void Add(TValue item) 
{
    if(!_Container.Select(p => p.Value).Contains(item, _equalityComparer) 
        _Container.Add(Indexed.Create(_Index++, item)); 
}
```

Where `_equalityComparer` is an `IEqualityComparer<Tuple<Edge,int>>` which returns true if the Edges are equal.

This is a bit of a mess unfortunately, and I think it probably loses a lot of performance benefits you probably want from the `SortedSet`, but it may be the best you can get, since there's nothing in `System.Collections` geared towards this. If performance isn't important, you could just try a `Set` or even `List`, and just sort when you need to. Even if performance is important, you might still want to do a comparison and see if this is even much better.