# Creating C# SortedSet from existing collection

Tags: c#, sortedset

I have an existing HashSet with 6 items:{ Value: 3, Occurrence: 1 },{ Value: 1, Occurrence: 2 },{ Value: 4, Occurrence: 2 },{ Value: 5, Occurrence: 1 },{ Value: 2, Occurrence: 1 },{ Value: 6, Occurrence: 1 }

Element class:

```
internal class Element
{
    public Element(int value)
    {
         this.Value = value;
          this.Occurrence = 1;
    }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public int Occurrence { get; set; }
}
```

How I want to create a SortedSet from items of this hash set like this:

```
var sortedSet = new SortedSet<Element>(hashSet.AsEnumerable(), new SortedSetComparer());
```

SortedSetComparer:

```
 internal class SortedSetComparer : IComparer<Element>
 {
     public int Compare(Element x, Element y)
     {
         if (x != null && y != null)
         {
            if (x.Occurrence > y.Occurrence)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if (y.Occurrence > x.Occurrence)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

But in debug I see that only 2 first elements got into sorted set: {Value: 3, Occurrence: 1} and {Value: 1, Occurrence: 2}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not comparing the `Value` is your main issue. You are effectively saying `{ Value: 1, Occurrence: 2 }` and `{ Value: 4, Occurrence: 2 }` are the same **because that is what 0 signifies**.

Comment: I want them to be sorted by Occurrence not Value. Anyway shouldn't they all go to sorted set regardless of underlying comparer?

Comment: 'A set has no duplicates' - I didn't know that, my fault.. Could you post your answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: The .NET framework doesn't contain [a sortable collection that allows duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716423/c-sharp-sortable-collection-which-allows-duplicate-keys) out of the box. You will have to use tricks if you need one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) (and [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type))):

> Duplicate elements are not allowed.

Since in your comparison method you are returning 0 if two objects have the same `Occurrence` (but different `Value`), then the set believes those two objects are [equal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer.compare?view=netframework-4.8#definition). The net effect - it adds the first item for each `Occurrence` value and ignores the rest.

To solve this issue, your comparison must compare `Occurrence` **and then** compare `Value` as well. *0 should be returned only if **both** `Occurrence` and `Value` are equal.*